# Can't see the google map when I start my application at first

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am developing a map application by google map api v2 for Android, it works good a few days ago normally.But an Error occured yesterday , I can't see the map normally at first (when I start the application ) .The map is on the fragment as you can see below image link.
http://pan.baidu.com/s/1mgJQ4Xi

actually the menu on the **left is under the map fragment** ,it seemed the map had apper,because I can see the view of the google map, but the content of map is empty!

When I open the menu and select anthor fragment, and then return the map fragment, it works normally,the map is appear!!!(below image link)

http://pan.baidu.com/s/1qWjQ5Ik

Who can tell me what happened to my application?Thank very much(This is the first time to ask at StackOverFlow, hope can help me)!

PS:After this problem accured, the application can't run still I install the Google Services Framework on my phone!`(before this, I had Install Google Play Services and Google Play Store,There are a fact that the Google Play Services public a new version recently, will it effect my application?)`

Comment: Once update your Google play services by going to SDK Manager-->Extras-->Google play services